# mySQL replication - 5.5 master to 5.7 slave and phpmyadmin.pma_recent errors

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, replication

I have set up mySQL replication between two servers.

The master is running Ubuntu 14.04 with MySQL 5.5 and phpMyAdmin 4.0.10
The slave is running Ubuntu 16.04 with MySQL 5.7 and phpMyAdmin 4.5.4

I thought everything was running OK but checked the slave status the next day to find it had stopped with the error: `Error 'Table 'phpmyadmin.pma_recent' doesn't exist' on query.`

I have checked and the table does exist on both servers but the names differ slightly. The master is `pma_recent` (single underscore) and the slave is `pma__recent` (double underscore).

I have specified the databases I want replicating and didn't include the phpmyadmin database so I'm not sure why this would be causing a problem.

Can these tables be renamed? Would I need to change the config to point to the renamed tables?

Thanks in advance.